# How to implement a multi-column list similar to WinForm in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to achieve the following effect in HTML:
[Desired effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POAOX.png)
Like this:

```
1        6        11
2        7        12
3        8        13
4        9        14
5        10       15
```

Elements may vary in height, if the first column can't show all the elements, I want the extra elements to be shown in the second column, and so on. (horizontal scroll if it exceeds width)
The number of elements and their contents are not fixed.

I didn't find anything related online. Hope that solves it, thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This requires the column CSS layout. set an height and column-width, the browser will handle then dispatching elements through the columns : https://jsfiddle.net/0um5ra2w/ **no need of javascript** ;) SEE https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment and to complete @tacoshy answer:

> column-width + height will allow horizontal overflow https://jsfiddle.net/0um5ra2w/ -|-  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns . column-count will only draw a fixed amount of columns :)

```css
ul{
  column-width:200px;
  height:5em;
  overflow:auto;
  
  /*demo purpose*/
  counter-reset:spans;
}
li:before{
  counter-increment:spans;
  content:counter(spans);
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li></ul>
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `column-count`-property to the wrapping parent element:

```css
.container {
  column-count: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
  <div>13</div>
  <div>14</div>
  <div>15</div>
</div>
```

Comment: To get the horizontal scroll, you can add a `max-height` and `overflow:auto` to the container

Comment: column-width + height will allow horizontal overflow https://jsfiddle.net/0um5ra2w/ -|-  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns . column-count will only draw a fixed amount of columns :)

Comment: Thanks, but the one I want is that the number of columns is not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can find something here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Mastering_Wrapping_of_Flex_Items

```
.box {
    height: 300px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box>* {
    flex: 1 1 80px;
}
```

For an HTML like

```
   <div class="box">
    <div>One</div>
    <div>Two</div>
    <div>Three</div>
    <div>Four</div>
    <div>Five</div>
    <div>Six</div>
    <div>Seven</div>
    <div>Eight</div>
    <div>Nine</div>
    <div>Ten</div>
  </div>
```